# Can I get feature file path from a ScenarioResult object?

Tags: java, karate

Is it possible to get the feature file path from a ScenarioResult object? I tried different methods but I couldn't get what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without knowing the details, but `getScenario().getFeature().getResource().getFile()` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can do it is to write a little Java file to get the path.  Java code could use File utilities to infer path from the classpath root.

Then load up the java file/utility in your Karate background.

I would prefer Peter's answer though.